# XmlConfigurator.Configure() does not accept 0 arguments

Tags: log4net

I have code that used:

log4net.2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll

XmlConfigurator.Configure();

when I change this to use 
log4net\2.0.8\lib\netstandard1.3\log4net.dll

I get no overload for method 'Configure' takes 0 arguments.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution [here](https://stackify.com/making-log4net-net-core-work/) was to use the code:

```
 var logRepo = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
 XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepo, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```